# Laravel 5.8 getting error when "char" type column migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to change my char type column default value using php artisan migrate command in laraval 5.8 but getting following error:

```
Unknown column type "char" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

My current script following:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddTypeDeafultValueProjectsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{

    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->char('type', 50)->nullable(true)->change();
    });



}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //
    });
}
}
```

I did not face issue with other data type column but only for char got above error.
Could please help me to fix this?

Comment: It's not possible to change an existing column to char. From the documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/sft7r6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add following scripts on your migration scripts:

Add following under or above use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

```
 use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\StringType; use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
```

After that add following scripts on inside up function and try php artisan migrate again.

```
    if (!Type::hasType('char')) {
        Type::addType('char', StringType::class);
    }
```